# SQL query to JSON_OBJECT and DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to output a query result as a JSON object using `JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT())` (that works just fine). I can't use `DISTINCT` within the JSON_OBJECT command and using `GROUP BY` will not output the whole result as one JSON but as many rows (each then a JSON). Example:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(\'id\', `id`, ...)) FROM table
```

That works fine but doesn't filter out the duplicates. I tried :

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(\'id\', `id`, \'title\', DISTINCT(`title`), ...)) FROM table
```

And :

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(\'id\', `id`, \'title\', `title`, ...)) FROM table GROUP BY `title`
```

But the former is wrong (syntax wise) and the latter splits the result in multiple rows. Can someone explain me how to achieve this? Like :

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(\'id\', `id`, ...)) FROM table
```

But with unique results only.

Comment: MYSQL

In the end I did a ordinary but more complex sql query and did the JSON converting in the server language rather than with SQL directly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap the duplicated query as a subquery and distinct from it?

`select distinct xyz from (
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(\'id\',`id`, ...)) as xyz FROM table) table1
);`

Comment: I doubt it, as the inner query returns a JSON and not a row representation but I'll give it a try.